# Elm architecture usage with elm-mdl library

Tags: elm

What is the recommended way to have mdl components affect the layout of the page in a single-page application using elm and elm-mdl?

Can we pass the layout messages, like `Model.Layout.ToggleDrawer` directly to `model.mdl` (in the standard setup), and if yes, how?

Or should we maintain a separated record element in the model, like `model.layout : Material.Layout.Model`, to which we forward these messages? But in this case, how to initialize the view?

#### Context

I am using `elm-mdl` version 8.1.0, with `elm` version `0.18`. I am trying to layout the basic architecture for a single-page application with elm, and this library. I have taken inspiration from [here](https://github.com/knewter/time-tracker) and [there](https://github.com/vipentti/elm-mdl-dashboard), as well as [this ticket](https://github.com/debois/elm-mdl/issues/42), but I have not seen what I was looking for, or understood it if it was there.

#### Examples of what I tried

For re-usability, the main model of my application is the only one containing a `Material.Model` entry:

```
type alias Model = 
    { drawer : MyDrawer
    , ...
    , mdl : Material.Model
    }
```

From the component `MyDrawer`, I want to define a button that will send a `ToggleSignal`. I have a case in my main `update` method that forwards this signal to the `Model.Layout.update` method, using the `Model.Layout.ToggleSignal`. However, the return type of this call is a `Material.Layout.Model`, which I don't have in my own `Model`.

If I define add a `layout : Material.Layout.Model` to my own model, I can forward the calls to this element, but how do I initialize the view? My view so far is this:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Layout.render Mdl
        model
        [ Layout.fixedHeader
        , ...
```

According to the signature of `Layout.render`, since my model contains a `layout` field, this should be taken into account. The relevant part of my update method is

```
ToggleDrawer ->
    let
        ( updatedLayout, cmd ) = Material.Layout.update Material.Layout.ToggleDrawer model.layout
        ( updatedDrawer, _ ) = Drawer.update subMsg model.drawer
    in
        ( { model | drawer = updatedDrawer, layout = updatedLayout }, Cmd.map MdlLayout cmd )
```

And yet, when clicking on the button, the drawer does not hide.

Thank you in advance for any help about this - the library and the language are such a joy to use already!

Answer (score 0):

The `Material.Layout.render` function retrieves its model from `model.mdl.layout`, not from `model.layout`.

A good way to toggle the drawer is to use [`toggleDrawer`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-mdl/8.1.0/Material-Layout#toggleDrawer) to issue a suitable command in your `update` function, like so:

```
ToggleDrawer -> 
    let
        ( updatedDrawer, _ ) = Drawer.update subMsg model.drawer
    in
        ( { model | drawer = updatedDrawer, layout = updatedLayout }
        , Layout.toggleDrawer Mdl
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this still does not quite work. `Layout.toggleDrawer Mdl` is just a `Msg`, and the compiler complains that it expects a `Cmd Msg`. From [there](https://medium.com/elm-shorts/how-to-turn-a-msg-into-a-cmd-msg-in-elm-5dd095175d84#.knp158c45), I used the function `send` to turn it into a `Cmd Msg`. The code compiles, but clicking on the button does not do anything. Should I also have forward the `Layout.Messages` to the Mdl layout component, or is this done by `mdl` internally? Thanks for your help